# Is every continuous function defined on a sphere Riemann-integrable?

Tags: calculus, integration, general-topology, multivariable-calculus

> Consider sphere $B$ defined by the equation: $x^2+y^2+z^2 \le 1$. Is every continuous function defined on the sphere  Riemann-integrable?

I have a hunch that the Jordan measure is the key to solving this problem. I know that if a function is continuous on a set and the set's boundary has measure $0$, then the function is integrable.

In this case, the boundary of the set is the set itself. And so, the boundary is the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$. Loosely speaking, we want the sphere to have $0$ volume. And I guess that is the case. 
 
So, the answer to my question is affirmative?

Comment: How do you even define a Riemann integral on a sphere?

Comment: @freakish  I, too, wondered a little bit about it. I guess there is a mistake in the assignment and it should say $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1$ instead

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, sorry, but I do not understand the problem with the question. 
Why would it not be possible to integrate a function $f: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$ defined on a compact set?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos
Consider a cube containing the sphere and a function $F$ defined on the cube as
$F(\vec{p}) = f(\vec{p})$ if $\vec{p} \in B$ and $0$ otherwise

Comment: With that approach **any** (continuous or not) function defined on a zero-measure set is Riemann integrable. And the integral is $0$. But that is so trivial. The question about closed ball (or more generally: closure of an open subset) instead of a sphere is more interesting.

Comment: @freakish  I have edited my question to cater for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In many textbooks the Riemann integral in ${\mathbb R}^n$ is first introduced for cubes $I:=[{-a},a]^n$ by means of Riemann sums. One then proves, among else, that for functions $f:\>I\to{\mathbb R}$ which are bounded on $I$ and continuous up to a set $N\subset I$ of $n$-dimensional Jordan measure $0$ the integral $\int_I f(x)\>{\rm d}(x)$ exists.

In order to integrate over arbitrary domains $B$ one defines
$$\int_B  f(x)\>{\rm d}(x):=\int_I 1_B(x)\> f(x)\>{\rm d}(x)\ .\tag{1}$$
If $f$ is continuous on $B$, and the boundary $\partial B$ has Jordan measure zero, then the integral $(1)$ exists.

In the case of a ball $B\subset{\mathbb R}^3$ the boundary $\partial B$ is a sphere. Such a sphere can be covered with finitely many patches which are $C^1$-images of compact rectangles in the $(u,v)$-plane. Such patches then have three-dimensional Jordan measure $0$.